# Error when using Meteor.wrapAsync. "Error: Future resolved more than once"

Tags: meteor

I use Meteor.wrapAsync to wrap my standard node.js function "sendMessage".

And I use looping to call Meteor.wrapAsync and execute the sendMessageSync.

But then I got Error: "Error: Future resolved more than once"

Why I got that error ?

Here is my code:

```
//Every 10 seconds get messages and send.
Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    var messages = getMessagesFromDb();

    //Send message every two seconds.
    Meteor.setInterval(sendAllMessages, 2000);

    var i = 0;

    function sendAllMessages() {
        if (i++ < messages.length) {
            //Get the sync version of sendMessage.
            var sendMessageSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(sendMessage);

            var result = sendMessageSync('is4ags', messages[i - 1]);

            //Error:  "Exception in callback of async function: Error: Future resolved more than once"
            console.log('sendMessage response: ' + result);
        }
    }
}, 10000);

//sendMessage is standard node.js function that accept callback.
function sendMessage(toAddress, message, cb) {
    //sendMessage Implementations.
}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I have Meteor.clearInterval() but I am still getting this error.

Comment: @Zacho yes, Please see this: https://forums.meteor.com/t/error-when-using-meteor-wrapasync-error-future-resolved-more-than-once/3543 . See avital answer.

Comment: @Argus thanks. I do not see any helpful answers there but I think I have it figured out.

Comment: @Zacho in my case, Fiber.return called more than once. It happened somewhere inside callbacks (on my code, probably callback inside sendMessage resolved more than once).

Comment: @Agus use Promise.all in this scenerio.